# How do I convert decimal numbers to binary in Perl?

Tags: perl, algorithm, binary, decimal

I am trying to make a program that converts decimal numbers or text into binary numbers in Perl. The program asks for user input of a character or string and then prints out the result to the console. How do I do this? My code I have been working on is below, but I cannot seem to fix it.

```
print "Enter a number to convert: ";
chomp($decimal = <STDIN>);
print "\nConverting $number to binary...\n";
$remainder = $decimal%2;
while($decimal > 0)
{
    $decimal/2;
    print $remainder;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

`$decimal/2;` isn't affecting `$decimal`

You probably want `$decimal /= 2;` or if you want to be cool, then `$decimal >>= 1;`

But really, really, you probably just want:

`printf "%b\n", $decimal;`

Comment: what does /= mean and what does printf do? Im sorry, im kind of new to perl

Comment: `/=` is division-assignment, in other words `$decimal /= 2` is equivalent to `$decimal = $decimal / 2`. `printf` is a formatted print function. If you really so new to programming that these aren't familiar to you, I would strongly suggest buying a book on Perl to get started with, rather than relying solely on asking questions to the Internet.

Comment: '$decimal /= 2;' is shorthand for '$decimal = $decimal / 2;'

A line like `$decimal/2;` doesn't do anything.  It's exactly like having a line like `42;`

printf means "print formatted".  The '%b' means that the argument will be converted to binary when it's being output.

Comment: also, i ran the input that you gave me and it converted the number properly, however, it kept printing the answer to the screen infinitely. Obviously there is something wrong with the logic of my while loop, but i do not see what it is.

Comment: @David If you used the `printf` line, then there is no need for a loop at all. The `printf` line does the complete job of converting a number to its binary representation and then printing it. Do try to find an introductory text on Perl. You're not going to get very far by copy-pasting other peoples' code that you don't really understand.

Comment: oh yeah duh sorry. /= is like ++ or --. sorry i wasn't paying attention. And i appreciate what you are saying, however, i just joined this site a couple days ago. I have been programming in different languages a lot recently and I just had a few questions that i couldnt work out.

Comment: another advantage of using `printf` or `sprintf` is that they are `C` routines and will be orders of magnitude faster than any multi-step Perl solution

Comment: @David No `/=` isn't like `++`. [`++` is special in Perl.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) [`$a /= $b` is an assignment operator that is functionally equivalent to `$a = $a / $b` ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators) `$a++` and `++$a` are almost the same as `$a += 1`, except that `++` can increment letters as well.

Answer (score 14):

Try this for decimal-to-binary conversion:

```
my $bin = sprintf ("%b", $dec);
```

To get each bit:

```
my @bits = split(//, $bin);
```

Then you can manipulate each bit, change the MSB index and so on.

Comment: For leading zeros, say for a total of 8 digits, use `my $bin = sprintf ("%.8b", $dec);`. Sample: `00000001`

Comment: actually, you may want to say `my @bits = reverse split(//, $bin)` so that `$bits[0]` ends up being the LSB.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few methods to convert from decimal to binary listed in [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html)
([How do I convert between numeric representations/bases/radixes?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-convert-between-numeric-representations/bases/radixes?)).

[sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) is a good choice.

Answer (score 8):

I have these aliases in my *.bash_profile* for quick conversions on the command line:

```
# from-decimal
alias d2h="perl -e 'printf qq|%X\n|, int( shift )'"
alias d2o="perl -e 'printf qq|%o\n|, int( shift )'"
alias d2b="perl -e 'printf qq|%b\n|, int( shift )'"
# from-hex
alias h2d="perl -e 'printf qq|%d\n|, hex( shift )'"
alias h2o="perl -e 'printf qq|%o\n|, hex( shift )'"
alias h2b="perl -e 'printf qq|%b\n|, hex( shift )'"
# from-octal
alias o2h="perl -e 'printf qq|%X\n|, oct( shift )'"
alias o2d="perl -e 'printf qq|%d\n|, oct( shift )'"
alias o2b="perl -e 'printf qq|%b\n|, oct( shift )'"
# from-binary
alias b2h="perl -e 'printf qq|%X\n|, oct( q|0b| . shift )'"
alias b2d="perl -e 'printf qq|%d\n|, oct( q|0b| . shift )'"
alias b2o="perl -e 'printf qq|%o\n|, oct( q|0b| . shift )'"
```

Comment: why were the from-binary (`b2_`) conversions omitted? i believe the following match your convention: `alias b2h="perl -e 'printf qq|%X\n|, oct( q|0b| . shift )'"`, `alias b2d="perl -e 'printf qq|%d\n|, oct( q|0b| . shift )'"`, `alias b2o="perl -e 'printf qq|%o\n|, oct( q|0b| . shift )'"`. but BTW if using bash, the to-decimal (`_2d`) conversions are cheaper and easier to use the built-in expansion, e.g. `echo $((16#F)) $((2#111))` to interpret `F` as hex, `111` as binary. which outputs decimal `15` and `7`

Comment: @ardnew No reason for omitting anything other than I don't use them. Yours would be find and if you want to edit the answer to add them that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias b2d="perl -e 'printf qq|%d\n|, unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . 1101 , -32)))'"
alias b2h="perl -e 'printf qq|%X\n|, unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . 1101 , -32)))'"
alias b2o="perl -e 'printf qq|%o\n|, unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . 1101 , -32)))'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
print "Enter a number to convert: ";
chomp(my $decimal = <STDIN>);

print "\nConverting $decimal to binary...\n";

my @array;
my $num;

while($decimal >= 1)
{
    if($decimal == 1) {

        $num .= 1;
        last;
    }

    my $remainder = $decimal%2;
    $num .= $remainder;
    $decimal = $decimal/2;
}

print $num."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to convert decimal to binary, hope it helps:

```
print "Enter a number to convert: ";
chomp($decimal = <STDIN>);
print "\nConverting $number to binary...\n";
$ans=0;$i=1;
while($decimal > 0)
{
    $remainder = $decimal%2;
    $ans=$ans+$remainder*$i;
    $i=$i*10;
    $decimal >>= 1
}
print $ans
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following code. It will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "Enter a decimal number \n";

my $dec_number = <STDIN>;
chomp($dec_number);

my $reminder;
my $result;

while ($dec_number >= 1)
{
    $reminder = $dec_number % 2;       #Modulo division to get remainder
    $result = $reminder . $result;     #Concatenation of two numbers
    $dec_number = $dec_number / 2;     #New Value of decimal number to do next set of above operations
}

print "Binary number Output = ", $result, "\n";
```